# Session error in magento2

Tags: magento2, session

I am getting an error like this in the site. How can I resolve it? I am using Memcache for session storage. My Magento version is 2.1.15

> Warning: SessionHandler::read(): Unable to clear session lock record
>   in /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php on
>   line 22

Anyhelp thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when your session.save_handler PHP parameter is set to some another session storage than files (for example, redis, memcached, and so on). This is a known issue we’re working to resolve.

> Solutions:

- [Upgrade your Magento 2 code](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall.html#instgde-install-magento-update)
- Use the following workaround with existing code.

> Locate php.ini

Locate `php.ini` by entering the following command:

```
php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
```

Typical locations follow:

- Ubuntu: /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
- CentOS: /etc/php.ini

> Workaround

1. As a user with root privileges, open php.ini in a text editor.
2. Locate session.save_handler
3. Set it in any of the following ways:

**To comment it out:**

```
;session.save_path = <path>
```

**To set it to a file system path:**

```
session.save_handler = files
```

References:

1. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_session.html
2. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5319

**I hope this will help**